# Trying to recursively reverse a linked list passed as an argument without modifying it, returning a new one

Tags: typescript, algorithm, recursion, linked-list, singly-linked-list

My current implementation works with a list length of less than or equal to two. Anything larger I end up losing the nodes in the middle. How can I scale that return object after the recursive call to work of any length of the list argument while also retaining the nodes in the middle?

Type List will reference the head of the list where ConsCell will be a node in the list

```
type List = null | ConsCell;

type ConsCell = {
  readonly first: number;
  readonly rest: List;
}
```

```
function reverse(list: List): List {

}
```

Implement the reverse function so that it returns the reverse of the input
list.

For example:

input: null (empty list)
output: null

input: { first: 1, rest: null }
output: { first: 1, rest: null }

input: { first: 1, rest: { first: 2, rest: { first: 3, rest: null } } }
output: { first: 3, rest: { first: 2, rest: { first: 1, rest: null } } }

Remember, you're **not modifying the input list**, you're returning a **new**
list

Current solution:

```
function reverse(list: List): List {

  if(!list) {
    return null;
  }
  
  else if(list.rest == null) {
    return {
      first: list.first,
      rest: list.rest

    };
  }

  else {

  let oldRest: List = reverse(list.rest);

  return {
    first: oldRest.first,
      rest: {
        first: list.first,
        rest: null
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible with all of the following apparent constraints in your attempt:

- recursive
- single pass
- no helper or inner function
- can't modify function signature (parameters and return types)
- not using extra space

The problem is, you have to keep track of the new head created all the way at the bottom of the call stack while also having access to the most recent previous node so you can set its next node.

Options (each one breaks one of the above constraints and are mostly not good, except the first):

1. Do it iteratively, which is better anyway (easier to code since all state is accessible, less overhead, no risk of stack overflow).
2. Do it in two passes linearly: one pass to copy the linked list, another pass to reverse it using any in-place linked list reversal algorithm.
3. Do it with an inner or helper function that supports returning both nodes at once (shown below).
4. Do it with an inner function that modifies the head in the closure (shown below).
5. Keep state in default parameters that you hope the top-level caller won't touch (shown below).
6. Do it quadratically by returning the head and repeatedly walking to its tail to extend it by one node.

Here's option 3, packing up two return values with a helper or inner function:

```js
/**
 * @template T
 * @typedef {{readonly val: T, readonly next?: ListNode<T>}} ListNode<T>
 */
/**
 * @template T
 * @typedef {{readonly val: T, next?: ListNode<T> | null}} MutableListNode
 */

/**
 * @template T
 * @param {ListNode<T>} ll
 * @returns {ListNode<T> | null}
 */
const reverseLL = ll => {
  /**
   * @param {ListNode<T>} ll
   * @returns {{head: ListNode<T>, prev: MutableListNode<T>}}
   */
  const reverse = ll => {
    if (!ll) {
      return null;
    }
    else if (!ll.next) {
      const head = {val: ll.val};
      return {head, prev: head};
    }

    const {head, prev} = reverse(ll.next);
    prev.next = {val: ll.val, next: null};
    return {head, prev: prev.next};
  };

  return reverse(ll)?.head ?? null;
};

console.log(reverseLL(null));
console.log(reverseLL({val: 1}));
console.log(reverseLL({val: 1, next: {val: 2}}));
console.log(reverseLL({val: 1, next: {val: 2, next: {val: 3}}}));
const ll = {
  val: 1,
  next: {
    val: 2,
    next: {
      val: 3,
      next: {val: 4}
    }
  }
};
console.log(reverseLL(ll));
```

Better yet, taking advantage of the closure to keep track of the head (option 4):

```js
/**
 * @template T
 * @typedef {{readonly val: T, readonly next?: ListNode<T>}} ListNode<T>
*/

/**
 * @template T
 * @param {ListNode<T>} ll
 * @returns {ListNode<T> | null}
 */
const reverseLL = ll => {
  let head = null;

  /**
   * @param {ListNode<T>} ll
   * @returns {{val: any, next?: null | {val: any, next?: null}}}
   */
  const reverse = ll => {
    if (!ll) {
      return null;
    }
    else if (!ll.next) {
      return head = { val: ll.val, next: null };
    }

    const prev = reverse(ll.next);
    prev.next = { val: ll.val, next: null };
    return prev.next;
  };

  reverse(ll);
  return head;
};

console.log(reverseLL(null));
console.log(reverseLL({ val: 1 }));
console.log(reverseLL({ val: 1, next: { val: 2 } }));
console.log(reverseLL({ val: 1, next: { val: 2, next: { val: 3 } } }));
const ll = {
  val: 1,
  next: {
    val: 2,
    next: {
      val: 3,
      next: {
        val: 4
      }
    }
  }
};
console.log(reverseLL(ll));
```

Here's another option (5), keeping state in parameters we expect the client to ignore. I don't like this, but if the inner or helper function approaches are forbidden and it's allowed to add optional parameters, it's certainly possible.

```js
const reverseLL = (ll, head={}, firstCall=true) => {
  if (!ll) {
    return null;
  }
  else if (!ll.next) {
    head.val = ll.val;
    head.next = null;
    return head;
  }

  const prev = reverseLL(ll.next, head, false);
  prev.next = {val: ll.val, next: null};
  return firstCall ? head : prev.next;
};

console.log(reverseLL(null));
console.log(reverseLL({val: 1}));
console.log(reverseLL({val: 1, next: {val: 2}}));
console.log(reverseLL({val: 1, next: {val: 2, next: {val: 3}}}));
const ll = {
  val: 1,
  next: {
    val: 2,
    next: {
      val: 3,
      next: {val: 4}
    }
  }
};
console.log(reverseLL(ll));
```

Pardon my key renaming and not using TS, in the interest of runnable examples. It should be easily convertable.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes programming with constraints can be very fun. Hopefully @ggorlen's answer helps you understand the bigger picture.

```
type List<T> = null | {
  readonly first: T
  readonly rest: List<T>
}
```

Here we use only the `reverse` function itself and a single parameter for the input list, `t` -

```
function reverse<T>(t: List<T>): List<T> {
  if (t == null)
    return null
  else if (t.rest == null)
    return t
  else
    return {
      first: reverse(t.rest)!.first,
      rest: reverse({
        first: t.first,
        rest: reverse(reverse(t.rest)!.rest)
      })
    }
}
```

Due to the constraints, it is not optimized for time/space. If variable assignment is allowed, you can reduce duplicated computations -

```
function reverse<T>(t: List<T>): List<T> {
  if (t == null) return null
  else if (t.rest == null) return t
  const r = reverse(t.rest)! // non-null guaranteed
  return {
    first: r.first,
    rest: reverse({
      first: t.first,
      rest: reverse(r.rest)
    })
  }
}
```

If logical *or* is allowed, you can collapse the conditionals -

```
function reverse<T>(t: List<T>): List<T> {
  if (t == null || t.rest == null) return t
  const r = reverse(t.rest)!
  return {
    first: r.first,
    rest: reverse({
      first: t.first,
      rest: reverse(r.rest)
    })
  }
}
```

If we allow for abstraction, we can write `cons` -

```
function cons<T>(value: T, t: List<T>): List<T> {
  return { first: value, rest: t }
}

function reverse<T>(t: List<T>): List<T> {
  if (t == null || t.rest == null) return t
  const r = reverse(t.rest)!
  return cons(
    r.first,
    reverse(cons(
      t.first,
      reverse(r.rest),
    ))
  )
}
```

Finally, if we are allowed abstraction we can write other list operations, such as `fold` -

```
function fold<T,R>(t: List<T>, state: R, func: (value: T, state: R) => R): R {
  if (t == null)
    return state
  else
    return fold(t.rest, func(t.first, state), func)
}
```

```
const add = (a, b) => a + b

const mylist = cons(1, cons(2, cons(3, null)))

console.log("sum", fold(mylist, 0, add))
```

```
6
```

Now we can derive `reverse` as a `fold` of `cons` -

```
function reverse<T>(t: List<T>): List<T> {
  return fold(t, null as List<T>, cons)
}
```

We can visualize output using another list operation we can appreciate, `toString` -

```
function toString<T>(t: List<T>): string {
  if (t == null)
    return "∅"
  else
    return String(t.first) + " -> " + toString(t.rest)
}
```

```
const mylist = cons(1, cons(2, cons(3, cons(4, cons(5, null)))))

console.log(toString(mylist))
console.log(toString(reverse(mylist)))
console.log(toString(mylist))
```

Re-printing the original list shows you `reverse` is an immutable operation -

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> ∅
5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> ∅ 
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> ∅
```